# Use of ABCMeta.register

Tags: python, metaclass, abc

What is the use of `ABCMeta`'s `register` method?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

It seems that if I have an abstract base class ABC, say, `Animal`, I can register a subclass of it using `register`:

```py
from abc import ABC

class Animal(ABC):
    pass

@Animal.register
class Dog:
    pass
```

But isn't this the very same as just defining the subclass as inheriting from the base class?

```py
class Dog(Animal): # same as wrapping with Animal.register decorator?
    pass
```

In other words, is it just a way to kind of dynamically define inheritance? Or am I missing some things that this method does?

Comment: I think the key part from the docs there is ". . . but the registering ABC won’t show up in their MRO (Method Resolution Order) nor will method implementations defined by the registering ABC be callable (not even via super())". I've never used `register` myself though.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of virtual base classes may seem funny if you come from a language with a different flavor of OOP.

There is a small example in the documentation of register that IMHO explains the concept of vitual base class

```
from abc import ABC

class MyABC(ABC):
    pass

MyABC.register(tuple)

assert issubclass(tuple, MyABC)
assert isinstance((), MyABC)
```

The assertions at the end of the code snippet are asking the following questions:

1. Is the type `tuple` a subtype of `MyABC`.
2. Is the literal `()` an instance of `MyABC`.

Since `tuple` is a builtin class and you can't redefine it, those assertions should fail, they don't because `ABCMeta.register` "makes" `issubclass` and `isinstance` believe that you modified the `tuple` type to inherit from `MyABC` when no actual inheritance is happening.

There are various use cases for this, you should take a  look at the [`collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: So, do you confirm what I said: "is it just a way to kind of dynamically define inheritance"?

Comment: I would rather say fake/mock inheritance  than define it. The registered type won't inherit any data or behavior from the "parent" type but the type system will still believe that they're related, think of it as advanced Duck Typing

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main use case for `register` is when you don't have control over the target class, `Dog` in your example.

Let's assume `Dog` is provided by a third-party library and you want to use it as one possible implementation (alongside others) of your ABC `Animal`. Then you could simply do:

```py
Animal.register(Dog)
```

(Which, as opposed to using the decorator as in your example, does not require access to the implementation of `Dog`.)